# Tensorflow native library issiue on m1 MAC

Tags: python, java, tensorflow, intellij-idea, java-11

I am using Intellij and JAVA 11  to run

```
System.out.println("Hello TensorFlow " + TensorFlow.version());
```

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>libtensorflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: darwin, architecture: aarch64. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java/README.md for possible solutions (such as building the library from source). Additional information on attempts to find the native library can be obtained by adding org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1 to the system properties of the JVM.
    at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:77)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:70)
    at org.tensorflowtest2.App.main(App.java:12)
```

Have not figure it out the problem.

Also Mac Terminal

```
% python
Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 12:20:14) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin

print(tf.__version__)
2.12.0
```

Comment: So if anyone wonders about the answer, apparently running TensorFlow on an m1 Mac is a lit tricky because of the architecture, so I did not want to mess with it and just switched to Windows, and it runs perfectly with no additional effort.